# Dealing with multiple "chained" postbacks from dynamically-created controls in a single page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, event-handling, postback

I'm trying to build a very specific search page for a project and I'm having lot of trouble dealing with multiple postbacks invoked by dynamically-generated controls on a single page.

The page has to work like this:

- There is a single checkbox, **"Detailed search"**, that causes a postback on checking/unchecking.

  - When detailed search is not active, a simple grid with contents and buttons is displayed. Nothing special.
  - When detailed search is active, **N** checkboxes must be generated from some dynamic data, that represent the sections where you want the search to happen. Below the checkboxes, an AJAX-enabled tab control will appear, initially with no tab pages.

    - When checking one of the section checkboxes, a postback will occur. After the postback, data will be searched in the section selected by  the user, then a new tab page containing a **grid view** of results and the name of the section will be added to the tab control. If the checkbox is unchecked, the tab page will disappear from the control, again, after a postback.

Now, the issue is that pretty much everything has to be generated dynamically, and that pretty much everything is connected to something else.

First issue: dealing with the **"Detailed search"** checkbox. Sounds easy, doesn't it? My initial idea was to set `Page.Viewstate["DetailedSearchEnabled"]` to `true` or `false` during the check/uncheck event handler, then create controls dynamically checking the value of `DetailedSearchEnabled` during `Page_Load`.

**Nope.** The postback event-handling happens between `Page_Load` and `Page_LoadComplete`. It would take an **additional refresh** for things to work as intended.

*<< Then I'll just generate the controls on `Page_LoadComplete`! >>*

**Nope.** Those controls need event handling as well, and if they're generated after `Page_Load` they will not be wired up correctly.

A possible solution would be generating everything in advance, on `Page_Load`, and only hiding/showing controls on `Page_LoadComplete`. But that is inefficient, and one important point of this search page is that only the minimum amount of controls should be generated.

The difficulty of this task seems to come from the way event wiring and the page life cycle work.

Surely there must be a better way of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First issue: dealing with the "Detailed search" check box.

The correct approach (if you want to use page post-backs) is as follows:

- In the CheckChanged event handler, save the value of the Checked property to `ViewState["DetailedSearchEnabled"]`. If the value is true, add the dynamic check boxes to the page. If the value is false, find and remove them.
- Override LoadViewState. After calling `base.LoadViewState`, re-create the dynamic check boxes and wire up their events if `ViewState["DetailedSearchEnabled"]` is true. Note that neither Page_Load nor Page_LoadComplete is the appropriate place to do this.

Yes, you should create the dynamic check boxes at two points in the page life cycle. I recommend a helper method.

In general, your event handlers should add or remove just the dynamic controls (if any) affected by those particular events, but LoadViewState should re-create *all* dynamic controls that existed from the previous page request. You must store enough information in view state for LoadViewState to do so.

My answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17755263/1127114) demonstrates how to add and remove dynamic controls. You may want to use it as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you should be using a CheckBoxList control to handle your dynamic checkboxes. You can add an remove items to the CheckBoxList during your post back and not have to worry about dynamically adding/removing actual controls/events to the form.

Here is a link to the msdn:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14atsyf5(v=vs.85).aspx

Here is some sample code:

```
Protected void Button1_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxList.Items.Add(new ListItem("TextValue1", "Value1"));
    CheckBoxList.Items.Add(new ListItem("TextValue2", "Value2"));
}
```

Comment: This would help solve (?) only a minimal part of the issue. The point of the question is not finding an existing solution but understanding how to tackle similar issues where multiple postbacks depend on each other

Comment: I don't believe there is ever a situation where you should "chain" multiple post backs together. If you are trying to do that you need to rethink your approach like you said "Surely there must be a better way of approaching this problem." This is it.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could still fall back on the quick-and-dirty old-fashioned ASP way.

- Use `Response.Write` or `<%...%>` to generate your dynamic controls as plain old HTML (simple form fields, e.g. `<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="1" />`).
- Make sure you have a form field for *every* piece of information you may need after the postback(s). If necessary, use hidden form fields to 're-post' values across subsequent postbacks.
- After postback, retrieve the values of the controls with the `Request` object.
- Use those values to adjust the generation of controls as you see fit.

You should be able to do all of this in `Page_Load`. The advantage is total freedom. The disadvantage is total freedom to make a big mess of your aspx. So you may want to migrate all this dirty code out of your aspx, and into a custom-made control, which you can then add to your aspx.

When generating your own HTML, be careful not to introduce XSS vulnerabilities. Use HtmlEncode where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making so many postbacks, it would be better to use jquery and ajax calls to load the controls as needed and then attach events to it or you can even use UpdatePnael for that. Help Links:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/ajax-basics-with-jquery-in-asp.net/
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested yourself, there is a better way to tackle it.

If I was in the same situation, I would create web methods for interacting with the page, and use client side to do the UI. I'm currently working mostly with angular JS, although it does come with a learning curve. You could use ng-hide/ng-show to bind to the checkbox event to display the detailed search. When the n number of checkboxes needs to be displayed, you can then just fill them in with ng-repeat, for each of the items you need to display, after a check/uncheck you can dynamically populate new controls etc. through web method calls if extra data is needed.

Pure ASP postbacks are quite clunky from my experience, and not really suited for building a maintainable dynamic UI.